# How to read bytes into BytesMut from a file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have this code to read a file into a `BytesMut`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

use bytes::{BufMut, BytesMut, Buf};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut b = BytesMut::with_capacity(10);
    f.read(b.as_mut())?;
    println!("The bytes: {:?}", b.len());
    Ok(())
}
```

But `b.len()` is always zero. The content of "foo.txt" is 0x00000010 (decimal 16). I can read into a `[0;10]` then convert it to a `BytesMut`, but is there a easy way do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `f.read()` call will write into an existing byte slice `&[u8]`. You have allocated space for 10 bytes, but the `BytesMut` doesn't yet hold 10 bytes. When it is deref'd into a byte slice it will return an empty slice, since it holds no data.

You'll want something like [`BytesMut::zeroed`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html#method.zeroed) and then it will work:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read, Result};
use bytes::BytesMut;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut b = BytesMut::zeroed(10);
    f.read(b.as_mut())?;
    println!("The bytes: {:?}", b.len());
    Ok(())
}
```

```
The bytes: 10
```

If you want to read the whole file without allocating prior, you can use [`std::io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html) with a `Writer` adapter via [`.writer()`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/buf/trait.BufMut.html#method.writer):

```
use bytes::{BufMut, BytesMut};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Result;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut b = BytesMut::new().writer();
    std::io::copy(&mut f, &mut b)?;
    println!("The bytes: {:?}", b.into_inner().len());
    Ok(())
}
```